# VLC RTP stream output capture with time label

Tags: cmd, vlc, marquee, timelapse

I am trying capture several images from a RTP stream in order to make a timelapse video, I would like the images show a on-screen time label. I have been using this command:

```
vlc.exe rtsp://192.168.1.49/live/main --video-filter=scene --marq-marquee=Time:%H:%M:%S --marq-position=9 --sub-filter=marq --scene-prefix=Timelapse- --scene-format=jpg --scene-path="c:\Timelapse" --scene-ratio 200 --sout-x264-lookahead=10 --sout-x264-tune=stillimage --run-time 43200
```

I can see the time label in the VLC interface, but when the images are saved they do not show this marquee.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

May be it's too late but i spend long time to find the solution:

This is part for loading module marq and adding overlay with time:

```
--sub-filter=marq --marq-marquee='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --marq-color=32768 --marq-position=20 --marq-opacity=25 --marq-refresh=-1 --marq-size=15
```

also you need to add module to transcode:

#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=2000,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,**sfilter=marq**}:duplicate{dst=http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv},dst=file{dst=stream.mp4,no-overwrite}}'

This is my full code:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --quiet-synchro --no-osd --sub-filter=marq --marq-marquee='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --marq-color=32768 --marq-position=20 --marq-opacity=25 --marq-refresh=-1 --marq-size=15 :v4l2-standard= :input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0 :live-caching=200 :sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=2000,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,sfilter=marq}:duplicate{dst=http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv},dst=file{dst=stream.mp4,no-overwrite}}' :sout-keep
```

Vlc stream via http and recording video fo file with timestamp overlay.

Hope it will help to other people who are looking for a way to get it.